# Can't use Javascript in Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, static

I tried to use java script in django, by following all the instructions and making the necessary changes in the settings.py file as well as using {% load static %} in my .html file. The CSS loads perfectly, but the .js file in the static/js folder does not.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/calcu.css' %}">

</head>

<form id="calci_form" method="get" action="operation">  
<select name="vehicle" id="veh" onChange="hideShow(this.value)"> 
        <option id="ve1" value="none" name="Select" selected="selected"></option>  
        <option id="ve2" value="2">17 </option>
        <option id="ve3" value="3">18 </option>
        <option id="ve4" value="4">19 </option>
        <option id="ve5" value="5">20</option> 
        <option id="ve6" value="6"> 21 </option> 
</select> 

    <select name="power" id="pwr" onchange="showHide()"> 
        <option id="pw1" value="none" name="Select" selected="selected"></option> 
        <option id="pw2" value="A">A</option> 
        <option id="pw3" value="B">B </option> 
        <option id="pw4" value="C"> C</option> 
        <option id="pw5" value="D">D</option>
        <option id="pw6" value="E"> E</option> 
    </select>
<label class="l1">X</label><input type="text" name="num1" class="tb1" value="{{fvalue}}">
<label class="l2">Y</label><input type="text" name="num2" class="tb2" value="{{svalue}}">
<label class="l3">Z</label><input type="text" id="txt" class="tb3" name="user_input" value={{result}}>
 <input type="submit" name="sym" class="btn1" value="Calculate">      
<!-- <input type="submit" name="mul" class="btn2" value="Calculate">  -->
</form>
</html>

<script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"> 
</script>
```

This is my html file.

my js file looks like this

```
function showHide(){
    alert(YOO)
    var x = document.getElementById("veh").options.length
    var v = document.getElementById("veh")
    var val = document.getElementById("pwr").value

     if(v.value == "none"){
        return 0
    } 

    for(i = 0; i<x; ++ i){
       v[0].style.visibility = "hidden"
    }
    if(val == "A"){
        document.getElementById("ve1").style.visibility = "visible"
        document.getElementById("ve2").style.visibility = "visible"
        document.getElementById("ve1").value = "Yoooooooooooooooo" 

    }   

}
```

Maybe there's something wrong with the js function that I wrote but it should at least show the alert which is also not being displayed

```
import os.path


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [

     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), 

]


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'styles')
```

I've included this in my settings.py and have also run manage.py collectstatic. Nothing's happened.
The CSS works fine.

Please help

Comment: goto your browser's network tab and check what is the status code for that javascript file

Comment: there's [no need](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/) to run `collectstatic` (or setup `STATIC_ROOT`) while using Django's development server

Comment: Is there an error in your console regarding the js file?

Comment: It worked. that alert box was an issue. but it's still not filtering the first list box based on the value of the second. anything wrong with my code? when i put quote within the textbox, the alert box showed which meant that it actually read from the file. However the first listbox is not being filtered based on the second.

Comment: You have `hideShow` instead of `showHide`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman bro I haven't defined hideShow. That's for the second listbox values to be filtered based on the first. look at the second listbox, it calls showHide()